# List SQL Views with Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone assist me with listing all SQL "views" with the column names?

I've tried using the query below but I also need the columns for views only.

```
select * from information_schema.view_column_usage
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem here, your query looks fine, column names are to be found in the column "COLUMN_NAME" of your query.

Answer (score 0):

What format do you want the results in? The following query will list all the views on the system and the columns they reference.

```
SELECT 
    '[' + VIEW_SCHEMA + '].[' + VIEW_NAME + ']' as [View]
    ,'[' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '].[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']' as [Column]

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

View can be treated as normal tables in this example. Try this:

```
SELECT t.TABLE_SCHEMA, t.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
ON t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME IN (
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS)
```